# Understand function parameters(pass by value instead of by const reference) in boost::beast client example websocket_client_async_ssl.cpp

Tags: boost, boost-asio, boost-beast-websocket

Reference:
boost_1_78_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_resolver/async_resolve/overload1.html

```
template<
    typename ResolveHandler = DEFAULT>
DEDUCED async_resolve(
    const query & q,
    ResolveHandler && handler = DEFAULT);
```

> The handler to be called when the resolve operation completes. Copies
> will be made of the handler as required. The function signature of the
> handler must be:

```
void handler(
  const boost::system::error_code& error, // Result of operation.
  resolver::results_type results // Resolved endpoints as a range.
);
```

boost_1_78_0/libs/beast/example/websocket/client/async-ssl/websocket_client_async_ssl.cpp

```
void run(char const *host, char const *port, char const *text) {
...
  resolver_.async_resolve(
      host, port,
      beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_resolve, shared_from_this()));
}

void on_resolve(beast::error_code ec, tcp::resolver::results_type results) {
  if (ec)
    return fail(ec, "resolve");

  // Set a timeout on the operation
  beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));

  // Make the connection on the IP address we get from a lookup
  beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).async_connect(
      results,
      beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_connect, shared_from_this()));
}
```

**Question 1**> Why does the `on_resolve` use the following function signature?

```
on_resolve(beast::error_code ec, tcp::resolver::results_type results)
```

As shown above, the first parameter(i.e. `ec`) is taken as pass-by value. This happens almost in all other functions which take a `beast::error_code` as an input parameter within sample code.

Instead of

```
on_resolve(const beast::error_code& ec, tcp::resolver::results_type results)
```

**Question 2**> Why doesn't the documentation suggest using the following instead?

```
on_resolve(const beast::error_code& ec, const tcp::resolver::results_type& results)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a cultural difference between Asio and Beast if you will.

> ### UPDATE
>
> There's some contention about my initial response.
>
> It turns out that at least Boost System's `error_code` recently got endowed with shiny new (non-standard) features, that makes it bigger. Perhaps big enough to make it more efficient to pass by reference.
>
> In the words of Vinnie Falco: *This needs to be studied again*.

### Rationale

In Asio, the standard "doctrine" is to take `error_code` by const&. In Beast, the standard practice is actually to pass by value, which is, IMO, how `error_code` is intended.

In essence, `error_code` is just a tuple of `(int, error_category const*)` which is trivially copied and therefore optimized. Passing by value allows compilers much more room for optimization, especially when inlining. A key factor is that value-arguments never create aliasing opportunities.

*(I can try to find a reference as I think some Beast devs are on record explaining this rationale.)*

### Why is it OK?

Any function that takes T by value is delegation-compatible with the *requirement* that it takes T by const reference, as long as T is copyable.

### Other thoughts

There may have been historical reasons why Asio preferred, or even mandated `error_code const&` in the past, but as far as I am aware, any of these reasons are obsolete.

Comment: Found a thread on cppslack #boost where they found `error_code const&` is bad for code-gen and indeed some discussion follows why Asio had been doing it "wrong" all along https://cpplang.slack.com/archives/C27KZLB0X/p1537406930000100

Comment: _"In an email to me Chris [Kohlhoff, sehe] pointed out that in early tests with passing error_code by value, the call stacks were so deep that the constructor for error_code (which sets the category to nullptr and error to zero) showed up in profiles."_ That seems to have been the historical reason for the Asio doctrine.

Comment: I didn't notice this until I ran clang-tidy which complaint about this. Now I will change it back and continue to use the beast way. Many thanks!

Comment: I hope you saw my update after checking on the #beast cppslack channel! But yeah, `boost::system_error_code` still at most `3*sizeof(void*)` which could be fine. You might want to check code-gen/performance once in a while.